# What is the difference between these two buttons?

Tags: html, button

What is the difference between these two buttons?

```
<button>caption</button>
<input type="button" value="caption" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `button` element can contain other HTML elements, for example images.

See also here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp says to `<button>`:

> important: If you use the  element in an HTML form, different
>   browsers may submit different values. Internet Explorer, prior version
>   9, will submit the text between the  and  tags, while
>   other browsers will submit the content of the value attribute. Use the
>   `<input>` element to create buttons in an HTML form.